# Flex Mobile StageWebView not displaying

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, stagewebview

I'm having issue on displaying the StageWebView on Flex Mobile 4.6 (Flash Builder 4.6), when I created it dynamically, the events are called properly but nothing is visible, here's my code:

```
<components:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:components="spark.components.*" 
             actionBarVisible="false"
             title="ActivityView"
             creationComplete="init()"
             >
<components:layout>
    <s:BasicLayout/>
</components:layout>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var webView:StageWebView;

        protected function init():void {
            webView = new StageWebView();
            webView.stage = this.stage;
            webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(5, 20, screen.width-10, screen.height-40);
            webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onURLLoadComplete);
            webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, onLocationChange);
            webView.loadURL("http://google.com");
        }

        protected function onURLLoadComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            trace("Load Complete");
        }

        protected function onLocationChange(event:LocationChangeEvent):void
        {
            trace("Location change: " + event.location);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</components:View>
```

Comment: I managed to solved this finally, by creating the stagewebview after addedToStage is called. 

    <components:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:components="spark.components.*" 
             actionBarVisible="false"
             title="ActivityView"
             addedToStage="init()"
             >

Answer (score 0):

`webView.stage = this.stage;`

When it's in `creationComplete` event handler, `this.stage` is still null.

You should put the `init()` inside of `addedToStage` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage instead, so:

webView.stage = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.stage;

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest way to add StageWebView is to add the StageWebView in createdChildren() (you have to define width and height of web view manually as the width and height of parent view will be 0) or during viewActiveEvent state.

Judah has written a very good WebView class which is much easier to use http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2011/01/16/stagewebview-uicomponent/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use StageWebViewBridge for displaying HTML, and Javascript communication. I hope this will help you to display HTML in flex Web, as well as AIR application. In your code, stage is not set for StageWebView, you just assign the webView.stage = this.stage in addedToStage handler or use the below method to load html.

```
        private var webView:StageWebViewBridge;

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            StageWebViewDisk.addEventListener(StageWebviewDiskEvent.END_DISK_PARSING, onInit );
            StageWebViewDisk.setDebugMode( true );
            StageWebViewDisk.initialize(stage);
        }

        private function onInit(e:StageWebviewDiskEvent):void
        {
            if(!webView)
                webView = new StageWebViewBridge(0, 300, 900, 300);
            webView.addEventListener(StageWebViewBridgeEvent.DEVICE_READY, onDeviceReady );
            webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
            webView.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onErrorHandler);
            webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, onLocationChange);
            var _view:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();
            _view.addChild(webView);
            addElement(_view);
            webView.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add stage like this...

```
private var _stage : Stage;

private function added_to_stage_handler():void
{
     _stage = this.stage;
     initStage();
}
private function initStage() : void
{
     webView.stage = _stage;
}
```